# On Create View in Fragment, getting null pointer exception when getting a string from EditText

Tags: java, android, fragment

I am getting a null pointer exception when getting a string from EditText. Is it because I am using a fragment, should I use an async task? I have no idea why this is happening. I get the error when I add the `s1 = text1.getText().toString();` line.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.tromto.analyzevalue.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

 </LinearLayout>



public class MyFragment1 extends Fragment {
    EditText text1;
    Button button1;
    String s1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        Toast t = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Section 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        t.show();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        text1 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        s1 = text1.getText().toString();

        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to `findViewById` from the Fragment's parent Activity. Instead, you should findViewById in your Fragment's View.

use:

```
text1 = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

instead of:

```
text1 = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1);
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, consider the fact, that your EditText will have an empty value (or its default value) at this point. No critic, just a note.

Comment: The default value wouldn't cause an error at this line, It may cause problems after that though.

Comment: So where should I put the edit text to listen to the user's value. Should I go with an async task or what is the best procedure?

Comment: That's a different question, but anyway, you just have to set OnClickListener to your button and take the EditText's value from there

Comment: I did set a button to take the edittext's value but as @Knickedi predicted the Edittext has an empty value.

Comment: you can set a default value in the xml by adding `android:text="default text here"` or dynamically after declaring `text1` using `text1.setText("default text here");`

Answer (score -2):

I just answered similar question. You have empty value in EditText1 on start. Do not use solutions as this on create, or fill some text inside if you must.